# Prove that $7$ is a primitive root modulo $p=2^s+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

I need help with the following question:

> If $1<s\in \mathbb N$ and $p=2^s+1$ is prime, so $7$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

**My thoughts:** First I know: $\phi(p)=p-1=2^s$. So if $r$ is the order of $7$ modulo $p$ then $r | \phi (p)=2^s$ then $rc=2^s$ and I don't know how to continue.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Note: it is well known that $2^n+1$ prime implies $n=2^k$ for some $k$.  So, other than the easily handled case $2^2+1=5$  your exponent must be divisible by $4$.

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: Can I prove what?  That $2^n+1$ prime implies $n=2^k$?  Any reference on the [Fermat Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#:~:text=In%20other%20words%2C%20every%20prime,sequence%20A019434%20in%20the%20OEIS). will include the straight forward proof of that.

Comment: Thank you very much.